# What actually is brake horsepower (BHP)?

Tags: engine, engine-theory, power, acceleration, horsepower

I know that BHP is the measure of power of an engine. I realised that I have no idea how the number (for example 540 BHP) relates to the engine itself.

- Does 1 HP mean one rotation of the crankshaft per a given time? Or is there some other way of defining it?
- ***How do you define BHP?***
- Also, what is the difference between HP and BHP?